# Keep getting error when trying to upload image to Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

Here is my code:

```
 Future selectFile() async {
    final result =
        await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (result == null) return;
    final path = result.path;

    setState(() {
      file = File(path);
    });
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    if (file == null) return;

    final fileName = file!.path.split("/").last;
    final destination = "test/";

    Storage.uploadFile(destination, file!);
  }
```

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class Storage {
  static Future<void> uploadFile(String destination, File file) async {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(destination);

      await ref.putFile(file);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to work out why exactly the code does not upload a photo, I have changed the rules in firebase but to no avail and the folder is called test so if anyone could suggest what I do or how to test my firebase storage, that would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

I keep getting this error when I call uploadFile:

```
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:477)
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:276)
E/StorageException(27972):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:224)
E/StorageException(27972):  ... 5 more
I/flutter (27972): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
```

Firebase rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I created a new flutter application with the above code and just two buttons, so it seems it may be a flaw in my other application's dependencies or something like that rather than the code. Thank you to everyone who helped once I figure out how to get it to work on my original application I will update.

[Firebase Storage working on one application but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101662/firebase-storage-working-on-one-application-but-not-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference you created should look like this now you added ref to the destination.  please try the following

```dart
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$destination/${file.name}.${file.extension}');
```

**EDIT**

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();


final uploadTask = ref.child('$destination/${file.name}.${file.extension}')
    .putFile(file, SettableMetadata(
    contentType: "image/jpeg",
  ));
```

**Edit1***

Remove static from here.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class Storage {
  Future<void> uploadFile(String destination, File file) async {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(destination);

      await ref.putFile(file);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

When you wish to upload first make a reference

```
Storage _storage = Storage();
_storage.uploadFile(destination, file!);
```

This should work as expected

Comment: I modified my code so that the child receives the following: test/IMG_20220724_122550.jpg, but this did not solve the issue, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Try setting a metadata too. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately this does not work either.

Comment: Try once by removing the extension too. I mean now the child should refer only test/IMG_20220724_122550

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work either.

Comment: do you have a folder named test in firebase too?

Comment: There is a folder called test in Firebase storage, yes.

Comment: Edited my answer again. Try creating a ref reperately before accessing the child

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix the issue either, but thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Thank you but if you check my update I managed to get the code to work but it just doesn't seem to want to work on my current application when I created a new application with just two buttons it worked fine. So I have created a new post.

Comment: Yeah so the solution that i wrote is for the edit in current application

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem and it solve like this.

```
await ref.putData(await file.readAsBytes());
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference as I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

final firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

// late var user =  _auth.currentUser;

var postid = Uuid().v1();

Future postData( imageFile) async {

```
enter code here
print("******************** ${timeles}");
final user = await _auth.currentUser;
enter code here
UploadTask uploadTask =
    firebaseStorage.child("post_$postid.jpg").putFile(imageFile) ;
TaskSnapshot f = await uploadTask.timeout(Duration(seconds: 50));
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.timeout(Duration(seconds: 20));
enter code here
String Iurl =( await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();


enter code here
postref.doc(user?.uid).collection("posts").doc(postid).set({
  "postid": postid,
  "ownerid": user?.uid,
  "email": user?.email,
  "price": _price.text.trim(),
  "phone": _phoneControlle.text.trim(),
  "name": _name.text.trim(),
  "location": _title.text.trim(),
  "dateprice": timeles.toString(),
```

"mediaurl": Iurl,

```
});
return Iurl;
```

}