# Firebase Storage working on one application but not another

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

Context: I was trying to implement a feature on an app I have been developing to upload and store a photo, it was not working and I could not tell why as I felt my code was fine and searching on the internet did not resolve the issue. So I created a new application with just two buttons to see if I could store the image on there, and low and behold it magically works. Can anyone explain why and how I can get it to work on my original application.

**Code:**

```
Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: false,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ["png", "jpg"],
    );

    final path = result?.files.single.path;
    final name = result?.files.single.name;

    print(path);
    print(name);

    setState(() {
      file = File(path!);
      fileName = name;
    });
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    if (file == null) return;

    final destination = "test/${fileName}";

    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination).putFile(file!);
  }
```

I just don't understand how the exact same code can work on one application but not another, any help will be greatly appreciated.

For reference, this is the error I get when I try to upload an image on my original application.

```
I/flutter (27972): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a problem with the setup/project files of my application I returned to a commit before I had even touched Firebase and implemented everything from scratch and it now works on my original application. I am guessing when I first started messing around with firebase I installed the wrong version or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

So here you are using the upload file method as non static one and in the previous one you used a class directly without an instance of it..

For example

```dart
class Storage{
  uploadFile(){}
}
```

You should be using an instance of storage like

```
Storage _storage = Storage();
//Now to access any method in this class use it's instance as reference
_storage.uploadFile();
```

Comment: I don't know if there is an issue with the code because as I said it works on a different application, I would like to know why it doesn't work on current application but thanks I will try that tomorrow.